# Binomial Probability employees problem

Tags: probability, combinations

A company has $500$ employees, and $60\%$ of them have children.

Suppose that we randomly select 4 of these employees.

What is the probability that exactly 3 of the 4 employees selected have children?

We know that 300 of these employees have children.

I tried to figure it out, how to work with the binomial equation by the given's

Comment: This is not a binomially distributed random variable...  rather, you should be using the [*Hypergeometric Distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  This is a textbook example of a problem solved by hypergeometric distribution.  Read the link and you'll have all the information you need.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do use the Binomial distribution, it is an excellent approximation, with relative error about 0.2%.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the first person picked has kids is $\frac{300}{500}$. Conditional on that, the probability that the second person picked has kids is $\frac{299}{499}$. Conditional on all that, the probability the third person has kids is $\frac{298}{498}$. Conditional on all that, the probability the fourth person doesn't have kids is $\frac{200}{497}$. So multiply these together and scale by $4$ (since the person without kids could have been any of the four).

---

An alternative perspective: the number of quadruples where exactly three have kids is $\binom{300}{3}\cdot\binom{200}{1}$. There are $\binom{500}{4}$ quadruples in total, so divide the two to get the probability.